# '90s children's literary horror anthology book, including a story about a cruel cousin who later turns out to be an android

Tags: story-identification, horror, anthology-book

When I turned 10 years old back in 1992, my mother sent me a care package crammed with snacks, mad magazines, a journal, a new video game, and a book of horror stories, that had creepy illustrations for some of the stories.

The stories I remember most involve a boy with amnesia, whose cousin is a sadistically cruel to him, who later turns out to be an android, a story where four boys accidentally disturb a cairn which releases a long dead alien who summons his fleet to return to Earth, and another story where four kids enter a haunted house, and don't make it out.

All of the stories -- I believe there were 8 to 12 stories -- ended on a grim note, there wasn't a single happy ending. Trouble is, I can't remember the title, and I DESPERATELY want this book again, as I work in an elementary school setting, and I want to give my kids something AWESOME to read, consequences be damned.

Comment: Does the boy turn out to be an Android, or his cousin?